# QSqlRelationalDelegate in QSqlRelationalTableModel shows foreign key instead of its value

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, qt

Here is my code:

```
QSqlRelationalTableModel *model = new QSqlRelationalTableModel(this, db1);
model->setTable("syllabi");
model->setRelation(3, QSqlRelation("activity_types", "activity_type_id", "activity_type_name"));
model->select();
ui->tableView->setModel(model);
ui->tableView->setItemDelegate(new QSqlRelationalDelegate(ui->tableView));
```

Values in combo boxes show correctly, but when I change the value and select another cell of the table, the cell shows the ID (foreign key) instead of its value. 
Also, when I insert another value with this code

```
model->insertRow(model->rowCount());
model->setData(model->index(model->rowCount()-1, 0), teacherName);
```

there is a error:

> QODBCResult::exec: Unable to execute statement: "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'default' to data type int."

The tables did't join correctly?

**EDIT:**

Okay, now when I change value in combo box it deletes the whole row. What might be the reason?

The tables: https://yadi.sk/i/ujL15zD_hupvz

Comment: What is source field and source table for the underlying combo box? If the value is disappearing, it means there is no matching key for the changed value in the combo box. Also the ODBC error tells that you are inserting teacherName as nvarchar instead of an ID field. Show all the fields and their types so we can debug accurately.

Comment: @EmacsUser it's the same for every table I tried to connect. Now it's activity_type table. The foreign key is activity_type_id and it's substituted with combo boxes with activity_name's. 
There must be a key because I choose it from the combo box, and it's there! 
I tried to insert teacher_id instead of teacher_name, it works, thank you! But the first problem is still there:
I see activity_type_name in a cell, click it, it shows a combo box, I choose any value, the whole row is gone (it's still there but the cells are empty)

Comment: I noticed that when I add a new row and change something in it, it doesn't get deleted right away, only when I fill all the cells and it's sent to db (it can't be sent to db while there are empty fields), before that I can't access any fields in the table, only the last row. When I choose values in combo boxes they become integer indexes. After I fill all the fields all the row gets deleted (it's inserted into the database though).
Seems like I miss something very obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's pretty late, but anyway, here is the answer.

I have encountered the same problem but in pyqt. The problem was with `EditStrategy.OnFieldChange` That should behave like `OnRowChange` when inserting a new row but somehow keeps skipping lookups for relations during the edit of the new row. Changing the `EditStrategy` to `OnRowChange` solves the problem.

Here is the original [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68634621/qsqlrelationaldelegate-displays-foreign-key-id-of-the-related-record-instead-o#69259694) I got for my problem.