# QSqlRelationalDelegate displays foreign_key - id of the related record instead of name/value from Combobox

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt6, qsqlrelationaltablemodel

I am trying to add new rows to `QSqlRelationalModel` which is represented in `QTableView`.

I have set proper `QSqlRelationalDelegate` and proper `QSqlRelations` in the model. Displaying existing data from the database works fine. Columns with related data change to Comboboxes and I can choose options from the related tables.

However, when I try to create a new record by adding a row to the model, Comboboxes allow me to choose the proper value from the dropdown list, but after choosing it, the value changes to the ID of the related record as if no relational delegate was set.

**main.py**:

```
import sys

from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtCore import QModelIndex, Qt
from PyQt6.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlTableModel, QSqlRelationalTableModel, QSqlRelation, QSqlQuery, \
    QSqlRelationalDelegate
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QPushButton

class Ui_main(object):
    def setupUi(self, main):
        main.setObjectName("main")
        main.resize(781, 652)

        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(main)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 761, 631))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")

        # Replace values with your database configurations
        database = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        database.setDatabaseName('accounting.db')
        database.open()

        button_add = QPushButton("AddRow")
        button_add.clicked.connect(self.addRow)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(button_add)

        self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.tableView.setObjectName("tableView")
        self.tableView.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tableView)

        self.table_model = QSqlRelationalTableModel(main, database)
        self.table_model.setJoinMode(QSqlRelationalTableModel.JoinMode.LeftJoin)
        self.table_model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.EditStrategy.OnFieldChange)

        self.table_model.setTable('book_of_accounts')

        self.table_model.setRelation(4, QSqlRelation('account_type', 'id', 'name'))
        self.table_model.setRelation(7, QSqlRelation('subconto1', 'id', 'name'))
        self.table_model.setRelation(8, QSqlRelation('subconto2', 'id', 'name'))
        self.table_model.setRelation(9, QSqlRelation('subconto3', 'id', 'name'))

        self.table_model.select()

        self.tableView.setModel(self.table_model)
        self.tableView.setItemDelegate(QSqlRelationalDelegate(self.tableView))
        self.tableView.hideColumn(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(main)

    def addRow(self):
        self.tableView.sortByColumn(-1, Qt.SortOrder.AscendingOrder)
        count = self.table_model.rowCount(QModelIndex())
        self.table_model.insertRows(count, 1)
        self.tableView.scrollToBottom()

        self.tableView.updateGeometry()
        self.tableView.selectRow(count)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    window = Ui_main()
    window.setupUi(main_window)
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**Database**:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "book_of_accounts" (
    "id"    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "code"  varchar(4) NOT NULL,
    "belongs_to_id" bigint,
    "name"  varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
    "account_type_id"   bigint NOT NULL,
    "quantitative"  boolean NOT NULL,
    "monetary"  boolean NOT NULL,
    "subconto_1_id" bigint,
    "subconto_2_id" bigint,
    "subconto_3_id" bigint,
    CONSTRAINT "book_of_accounts_subconoto_3_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY("subconto_3_id") REFERENCES "subconto3" on delete cascade,
    CONSTRAINT "book_of_accounts_subconoto_2_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY("subconto_2_id") REFERENCES "subconto2" on delete cascade,
    CONSTRAINT "book_of_accounts_subconoto_1_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY("subconto_1_id") REFERENCES "subconto1" on delete cascade,
    CONSTRAINT "book_of_accounts_account_type_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY("account_type_id") REFERENCES "account_type",
    CONSTRAINT "book_of_accounts_belongs_to_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY("belongs_to_id") REFERENCES "book_of_accounts"
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "subconto3" (
    "id"    bigserial,
    "name"  varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "subconto3_pkey" PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "subconto2" (
    "id"    bigserial,
    "name"  varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "subconto2_pkey" PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "subconto1" (
    "id"    bigserial,
    "name"  varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "subconto1_pkey" PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "account_type" (
    "id"    bigserial,
    "name"  varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "account_type_pkey" PRIMARY KEY("id")
);

INSERT INTO "subconto3" ("id","name") VALUES (1,'< Ничего >');
INSERT INTO "subconto3" ("id","name") VALUES (2,'Цены');
INSERT INTO "subconto3" ("id","name") VALUES (3,'Подразделения');
INSERT INTO "subconto2" ("id","name") VALUES (1,'< Ничего >');
INSERT INTO "subconto2" ("id","name") VALUES (2,'Места хранения');
INSERT INTO "subconto2" ("id","name") VALUES (3,'Статьи затрат');
INSERT INTO "subconto2" ("id","name") VALUES (4,'Договора');
INSERT INTO "subconto2" ("id","name") VALUES (5,'Виды налогооблагаемого дохода');
INSERT INTO "subconto2" ("id","name") VALUES (6,'Движение денежных средств');
INSERT INTO "subconto2" ("id","name") VALUES (7,'Виды выбытия');
INSERT INTO "subconto1" ("id","name") VALUES (1,'< Ничего >');
INSERT INTO "subconto1" ("id","name") VALUES (2,'Основные средства');
INSERT INTO "subconto1" ("id","name") VALUES (3,'Нематериальные активы');
INSERT INTO "subconto1" ("id","name") VALUES (4,'Товаро-материальные запасы');
INSERT INTO "subconto1" ("id","name") VALUES (5,'Статьи затрат');
INSERT INTO "subconto1" ("id","name") VALUES (6,'Расходы будущих периодов');
INSERT INTO "subconto1" ("id","name") VALUES (7,'Контрагенты');
INSERT INTO "subconto1" ("id","name") VALUES (8,'Сотрудники');
INSERT INTO "subconto1" ("id","name") VALUES (9,'Налоги и отчисления');
INSERT INTO "subconto1" ("id","name") VALUES (10,'Движение денежных средств');
INSERT INTO "subconto1" ("id","name") VALUES (11,'Расчетные счета наши');
INSERT INTO "subconto1" ("id","name") VALUES (12,'Контрагенты и Сотрудники');
INSERT INTO "account_type" ("id","name") VALUES (1,'Активный');
INSERT INTO "account_type" ("id","name") VALUES (2,'Забалансовый');
INSERT INTO "account_type" ("id","name") VALUES (3,'Контр. Активный');
INSERT INTO "account_type" ("id","name") VALUES (4,'Контр. Пассивный');
INSERT INTO "account_type" ("id","name") VALUES (5,'Пассивный');
INSERT INTO "account_type" ("id","name") VALUES (6,'Транзитный');

INSERT INTO "book_of_accounts" ("id","code","belongs_to_id","name","account_type_id","quantitative","monetary","subconto_1_id","subconto_2_id","subconto_3_id") VALUES (1,'0000',NULL,'Остатки',5,0,0,1,1,1);
INSERT INTO "book_of_accounts" ("id","code","belongs_to_id","name","account_type_id","quantitative","monetary","subconto_1_id","subconto_2_id","subconto_3_id") VALUES (2,'0100',NULL,'СЧЕТА УЧЕТА ОСНОВНЫХ СРЕДСТВ',3,0,0,2,2,1);
INSERT INTO "book_of_accounts" ("id","code","belongs_to_id","name","account_type_id","quantitative","monetary","subconto_1_id","subconto_2_id","subconto_3_id") VALUES (3,'0110',2,'Земля',3,0,0,2,2,1);
INSERT INTO "book_of_accounts" ("id","code","belongs_to_id","name","account_type_id","quantitative","monetary","subconto_1_id","subconto_2_id","subconto_3_id") VALUES (4,'0111',2,'Благоустройство земли',1,0,0,2,2,1);
INSERT INTO "book_of_accounts" ("id","code","belongs_to_id","name","account_type_id","quantitative","monetary","subconto_1_id","subconto_2_id","subconto_3_id") VALUES (5,'0112',2,'Благоустройство основных средств, полученных по договору долгосрочной аренды',1,0,0,2,2,1);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "bookofaccounts_code" ON "book_of_accounts" (
    "code"
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "bookofaccounts_belongs_to_id" ON "book_of_accounts" (
    "belongs_to_id"
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "bookofaccounts_name" ON "book_of_accounts" (
    "name"
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "bookofaccounts_account_type_id" ON "book_of_accounts" (
    "account_type_id"
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "bookofaccounts_subconoto_1_id" ON "book_of_accounts" (
    "subconto_1_id"
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "bookofaccounts_subconoto_2_id" ON "book_of_accounts" (
    "subconto_2_id"
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "bookofaccounts_subconoto_3_id" ON "book_of_accounts" (
    "subconto_3_id"
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "subconto3_name" ON "subconto3" (
    "name"
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "subconto2_name" ON "subconto2" (
    "name"
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "subconto1_name" ON "subconto1" (
    "name"
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "accounttype_name" ON "account_type" (
    "name"
);
COMMIT;
```

This problem might be related to an [unanswered 6-years-old so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31460201/qsqlrelationaldelegate-in-qsqlrelationaltablemodel-shows-foreign-key-instead-of).

Comment: It would help a lot if you could provide a basic database (possibly using sqlite, so that it can be easily embedded in your question) and also try to reduce your code to a more compact version (just one code block) and avoiding unnecessary elements if they are not considered part of the problem. This would dramatically help us to better focus on the problem, instead of trying to reproduce it (which is a bit impossible right now, since we don't know what are the contents of the database) or understand what your code does (which is pretty hard, since it's very long).

Comment: @musicamante I have updated my question. Made the code minimal and added the database in sqlite. Hope that makes the question clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this issue comes from the use of `EditStrategy.OnFieldChange`.

In the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#EditStrategy-enum) it says that

> To prevent inserting only partly initialized rows into the database, `OnFieldChange` will behave like `OnRowChange` for newly inserted rows

But it looks like this behaviour isn't *complete* & the "invalid" state of the row is still preventing the lookups for the related fields. You'll notice that once the row is complete and written, it actually works fine.

If you switch the edit strategy to `EditStrategy.OnRowChange` it works as expected.

```
self.table_model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.EditStrategy.OnRowChange)
```

Below is an in-progress edit, where I've exited the 4th column drop down. It continues to show the value of the related field lookup.

[image: Image showing related field lookup working using OnRowChange edit strategy]

Comment: Now I can sleep well. Thanks). It indeed does not do lookups,  I could confirm it with delegates that ```sedModelData``` receives foreign keys in the editor instead of the field defined in ```setRelation``` of the model.

Comment: @MuslimbekAbduganiev great! It was a weird one, the behaviour really should be documented.

Comment: By the way, I think this problem is the same as the so question mentioned in my question. The difference is that that one uses c++ and 6 years old. Are there any appropriate guidelines regarding situations like this? I mean should I post on that question a new answer or comment and give a link to this answer?

Comment: I think it's fine to post an answer, and just link across to this one for context. Posting a comment wouldn't show the question as being answered & is easily missed.